# How to drag and drop files items inside a folder item using QFileSystemModel and QListView?

Tags: python, pyside2, qlistview, qfilesystemmodel

I'm creating a widget to explore and manage files inside my qt application. To construct that, I'm using a `QFileSystemModel` and a `QListView` with the `IconMode` view mode.

It should allow moving files (items) into folders (other items) with the `QListView`.

My question is how do I implement this?

First, I'm trying to override the `supportedDragActions` and `supportedDropActions` functions from `ContentFileSystemModel` to allow Move and Copy actions. Also, I override the `flags` function to enable drag and drop. Finally, I override the `canDropMimeData` and `dropMimeData` to check if they are running, but it looks like they are not.

The first problem is that the model does not allow to drop an item file into the `QListView` area once it displays a prohibited icon in the cursor (shown in the image below).

First, I have to set the model to allow the drops of items in folders. After that, I can implement the code to transfer the dragged items into the folder.

[image]

Code ready to reproduce the problem:

```
import sys
import os

from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *


class ContentFileSystemModel(QFileSystemModel):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ContentFileSystemModel, self).__init__()

    def supportedDragActions(self) -> Qt.DropActions:
        print("supportedDragActions")
        return Qt.MoveAction | super(ContentFileSystemModel, self).supportedDragActions() | Qt.CopyAction

    def supportedDropActions(self) -> Qt.DropActions:
        print("supportedDropActions")
        return Qt.MoveAction | super(ContentFileSystemModel, self).supportedDropActions() | Qt.CopyAction

    def flags(self, index: QModelIndex) -> Qt.ItemFlags:
        defaultFlags = super(ContentFileSystemModel, self).flags(index)
        if not index.isValid():
            return defaultFlags
        fileInfo = self.fileInfo(index)
        # The target
        if fileInfo.isDir():
            # Allowed drop
            return Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled | Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | defaultFlags
        # The source: should be directory( in that case)
        elif fileInfo.isFile():
            # Allowed drag
            return Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled | Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | defaultFlags
        return defaultFlags

    def canDropMimeData(self, data: QMimeData, action: Qt.DropAction,
                        row: int, column: int, parent: QModelIndex) -> bool:
        print("canDropMimeData")
        return True

    def dropMimeData(self, data: QMimeData, action: Qt.DropAction,
                     row: int, column: int, parent: QModelIndex) -> bool:
        print("dropMimeData")
        return True


def main(argv):
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    path = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop"
    file_system_model = ContentFileSystemModel()
    file_system_model.setRootPath(path)
    file_system_model.setReadOnly(False)

    lv_file_manager = QListView()
    lv_file_manager.setModel(file_system_model)
    lv_file_manager.setViewMode(QListView.IconMode)
    lv_file_manager.setRootIndex(file_system_model.index(path))
    lv_file_manager.setResizeMode(QListView.Adjust)

    lv_file_manager.setMovement(QListView.Static)
    lv_file_manager.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
    lv_file_manager.setWrapping(True)
    lv_file_manager.setAcceptDrops(True)
    lv_file_manager.setDragEnabled(True)
    lv_file_manager.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
    lv_file_manager.setUniformItemSizes(True)
    lv_file_manager.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
    lv_file_manager.setFlow(QListView.LeftToRight)

    lv_file_manager.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the wrong [movement](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#movement-prop) property, since you're using [`Static`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#Movement-enum):

> The items cannot be moved by the user.

When using the `IconMode`, that property is automatically set to `Free`, so you can just **remove** the following line:

```
lv_file_manager.setMovement(QListView.Static)
```

The other important implementations are in the model's `canDropMimeData()` (which must return `True` if the target is a writable directory) and `dropMimeData()` (that will actually move the files).

The final step is to override the `dragMoveEvent()` to prevent moving icons around the current view.

Note that the following changes have also been made:

- `flags()` should *not* return `ItemIsDragEnabled` if the target is a file;
- `setAcceptDrops(True)` and `setDragEnabled(True)` are not required as they are automatically set when the movement is *not* `Static` (which is the case when using the `IconMode` as explained above);
- `setDragDropMode()` is also not required;

```
class ContentFileSystemModel(QFileSystemModel):
    # ...
    def flags(self, index: QModelIndex) -> Qt.ItemFlags:
        defaultFlags = super(ContentFileSystemModel, self).flags(index)
        if not index.isValid():
            return defaultFlags
        fileInfo = self.fileInfo(index)
        if fileInfo.isDir():
            return Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled | Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | defaultFlags
        elif fileInfo.isFile():
            # files should *not* be drop enabled
            return Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | defaultFlags
        return defaultFlags

    def canDropMimeData(self, data: QMimeData, action: Qt.DropAction,
                        row: int, column: int, parent: QModelIndex) -> bool:
        if row < 0 and column < 0:
            target = self.fileInfo(parent)
        else:
            target = self.fileInfo(self.index(row, column, parent))
        return target.isDir() and target.isWritable()

    def dropMimeData(self, data: QMimeData, action: Qt.DropAction,
                     row: int, column: int, parent: QModelIndex) -> bool:
        if row < 0 and column < 0:
            targetDir = QDir(self.fileInfo(parent).absoluteFilePath())
        else:
            targetDir = QDir(self.fileInfo(self.index(row, column, parent)).absoluteFilePath())
        dataList = []
        # first check if the source is writable (so that we can move it) 
        # and that it doesn't already exist on the target path
        for url in data.text().splitlines():
            path = QUrl(url).toLocalFile()
            fileObject = QFile(path)
            if not fileObject.permissions() & QFile.WriteUser:
                return False
            targetPath = targetDir.absoluteFilePath(QFileInfo(path).fileName())
            if targetDir.exists(targetPath):
                return False
            dataList.append((fileObject, targetPath))
        # actually move the objects, you might want to add some feedback
        # if movement failed (eg, no space left) and eventually undo the
        # whole operation
        for fileObject, targetPath in dataList:
            if not fileObject.rename(targetPath):
                return False
        return True

class FileView(QListView):
    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        # accept drag movements only if the target supports drops
        if self.model().flags(self.indexAt(event.pos())) & Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled:
            super().dragMoveEvent(event)
        else:
            event.ignore()


def main(argv):
    # ...
    lv_file_manager = FileView()
```

Comment: Thanks, musicamante. When I remove that line, the items can be moved freely to other places in the `QListView`. However, once I would like to allow moving items only into folders, it is an undesirable feature. Anyway, it is progress once the model allows dropping the items and its call the `canDropMimeData` function. I'll try to restrict this drop only into folders. I'll report here any progress.

Comment: If you want to get more control on the drop target, you must override the `dropEvent` on the view. I've written a small file manager on my own some time ago with Qt, so if you could better clarify how your program should behave depending on the situation, I can give you some suggestions and possibly edit the answer.

Comment: I want to allow dragging items (files and folders) only into other folder items. When the user drops it somewhere other than a folder, nothing should happen. When the user drops it in a folder, it should be moved into there.

Comment: When I say moved, I mean remove the files from the current folder and put them in the folder where they were dropped.